# Actionscript, objects and event listeners

Tags: actionscript, event-handling

Say I have an object

```
var my_obj = new Object();
my_obj['key'] = value;
```

Is there a way to add an event listener to the value, like

```
my_obj['key'].addEventListener(Blah Blah);
```

I have a long(ish) list of buttons on the timeline (the layout is so different from section to section that just makes more sense to do on the timeline rather than trying to build the layouts via actionscript).

```
button1 = plays "frame label 1"
button2 = plays "frame label 2"
```

and so on....so I was just thinking of storing everything in an array

```
obj["button1"] = "framelabel1"
arr.push(obj);
```

Then I could just have one event handler for all of the buttons and use target to get the frame label value...

Comment: Could you please make us stop guessing what actually was the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you're asking in the exact way you've mentioned, here's an example:

```
var value:Sprite = new Sprite();

var my_obj = new Object();
my_obj['key'] = value;
```

So calling:

```
my_obj['key'].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _onEnterFrameHandler);
```

is exactly the same as calling:

```
value.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _onEnterFrameHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is an [IEventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html) or extends [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) you can add a listener to it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather obscure to me. My guess is that you need something triggered every time a value is set. If this is the case, then you have to create a custom class, and declare a getter-setter property there.

For instance:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestAccessor extends Sprite
    {
        private var someVarValue:uint = 0;

        public function TestAccessor()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function get someVar():uint
        {
            return someVarValue;
        }

        public function set someVar(value:uint):*
        {
            someVarValue = value;
            // this is the place where someVar is set.
            // do whatever else you like here,
            // you may choose to dispatch an event from here if you need.
        }

    }
}
```

Back in AS1-AS2 era we had `watch()` and `addProperty()` for that purpose, but these times are long since gone. For good. :)